# Show only current directory name (not full path) on bash prompt

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bashrc

The way my bash prompt is currently configured, it shows the whole path to the current directory. This is annoying when I'm deep inside a directory tree, as the prompt becomes so long that every command wraps into the next line. How do I make it show only the last part of the path?

This is what I have in my `.bashrc`:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"'
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Change the `\w` (lowercase) to `\W` (uppercase):

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
                                                                                       ^^
           this one waaaaaay over here ------------------------------------------------+
```

Have a look at the [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/index.html) for lots of fun details.  example:

```
user@host:/usr/local/bin$ echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ 

user@host:/usr/local/bin$ export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '

user@host:bin$
```

The `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable, if set, is a command that gets run before displaying the prompt specified in `PS1`.  In your case, `PROMPT_COMMAND` runs an `echo` statement with certain [ANSI escape sequences](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html) that [manipulate the titlebar of an Xterm](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html).

If you suspect your `PROMPT_COMMAND` is overriding your `PS1` prompt, you can `unset` it and test things out:

```
$ unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```

Finally, be sure that you're changing the `PS1` definition that actually gets used.  Common locations are `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`.  The system files are generally (but not always) run before the user files.

Comment: Hm... I'm afraid it's already \w, but it seems like that `case` statement overrides it when i'm on an xterm, and the problem seems to be with the `PWD` in the `PROMPT_COMMAND` line. Do you know what I should put there?

Comment: `\w` (lower case) sets it to full path, `\W` (uppercase) trims to the final bit.  the PROMPT_COMMAND is setting the window title in an xterm.  check your TERM variable; if it doesn't *start* with "xterm" or "rxvt" then PROMPT_COMMAND isn't even getting run.

Comment: Oh, yeah, duh. Sorry, I mixed upper and lowercase. That worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: Great answer. Make sure you reboot in order this to take effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

Simple bash replace command is

```
${VAR/pattern_to_find/pattern_to_replace}
```

For showing the last directory you can just do `${PWD/*\//}`, i.e. find any thing before and including the last '`/`' and replace it with nothing.

On my ubuntu machine I use:

```
export PS1='$(whoami):${PWD/*\//}#'.
```

Comment: I like this answer better than the accepted one because it's generic to any situation instead of just the special parsing logic of $PS1. Fewer more powerful tools are easier to remember and compose. :)

Answer (score 9):

My solution is to show the top three and bottom 2 directories when there are more than 5

So my prompt (which has other info too) looks like:

```
08:38:42 durrantm U2017 /home/durrantm/Dropbox/_/rails/everquote
```

when my pwd is actually

```
/home/durrantm/Dropbox/93_2016/work/code/ruby__rails/rails/everquote
```

My PS1 prompt is setup as follows:

```
HOST='\[\033[02;36m\]\h'; HOST=' '$HOST
TIME='\[\033[01;31m\]\t \[\033[01;32m\]'
LOCATION=' \[\033[01;34m\]`pwd | sed "s#\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/\).*\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}\)/\{0,1\}#\1_\2#g"`'
BRANCH=' \[\033[00;33m\]$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
PS1=$TIME$USER$HOST$LOCATION$BRANCH
```

`git_branch` is a function which shows current git branch, I keep it in my dotfiles, it is:

```
git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
  }
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

My solution for this is slightly different in regards to how do I export it, so thought I'd share it here:

Create another prompt string variable; PS5 and export the following string in your `.profile` / `.bash_profile` file:

> **\u**: Display the current username .
>
> **\W**: Print the base of current working directory.

```sh
# Display username and current directory only.
export PS5='export PS1="\u:\W$";';
```

Now whenever you need to use the shorthand-ed PS, just run: `eval $PS5`

---

Or even better yet, create an alias in your `.bash_aliases` file: (thanks to [@muru](https://superuser.com/questions/60555/show-only-current-directory-name-not-full-path-on-bash-prompt#comment2024129_1350301))

```
alias PS5='export PS1="\u:\W$";';
```

`source` again, and now you can just type `PS5` to switch.

Comment: This looks like a frankenalias. Why not just use an alias or a function?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this option is much easier, by simply doing:

```
echo $PWD | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev
```

So assign this to the PS1 variable in your .bashrc file:

```
PS1='$(PWD | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev)'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Show only current directory name (not full path) on bash prompt

Most of the other solutions did not work for me across all of my OSes that share my dot files: AIX, Windoze, and Linux.  The bash ports were old versions that didn't support certain constructs and I didn't want to fork another process (i.e. `sed`, `awk`, etc.) which is noticeably expensive under cygwin.

The following is long but performant:

```
# takes a number argument of the number of last dirs to show
function DIR_LAST {
    # read -a didn't seem to work under bash 3
    IFS='/' array=($PWD)
    len=${#array[@]}
    start=$((len - $1))
    # leading / if fewer dir args: /usr/flastname not usr/flastname
    if (( $start <= 1 )); then
        start=1
        echo -n /
    fi
    for (( i = $start; $i < $len; i++ )); do
        if (( $i > $start )); then
            echo -n /
        fi
        echo -n ${array[$i]}
    done
}
export PS1="\$(DIR_LAST 2) {$(hostname)} "
```

I want it to spit out:

```
/
/usr
/usr/foo
foo/bin
```

Notice the lack of a leading slash in the last line which is how I like it.  Also, you can spit out the last 3 directories by changing the arg to `DIR_LAST`.

Also, I tried to do this with a regex and `BASH_REMATCH` but bash v3 didn't seem to like the parens and I couldn't figure out how to properly escape them.  Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

```
root:~/project#  -> root:~/project(dev)#
```

add the following code to the end of your ~/.bashrc

```
force_color_prompt=yes
color_prompt=yes
parse_git_branch() {
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export PS1="\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[37m\]\W \[\e[32m\]$"
```

Put the above line at the end of ~/.bashrc, and everything should go well.
This will preserve the color and keeps things in beautiful way.

32m --> green

37m --> white