# How to shorten the no of characters display for the current directory in the prompt

Tags: ubuntu, bash, environment-variables

I am using bash, and in my .basrhrc: 
I have the following which defined how my prompt looks:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\w\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\!:\#\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

I think the \w display the current path of the shell.

Is there any way to limit the number of character used to display the current path of the shell?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/60555/show-only-current-directory-name-not-full-path-on-bash-prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\W` (capital "W") which will make your home directory (`/home/username`) display as a tilde ('~') and only show the basename of the current directory. So an example might look like:

```
dir:509:9$ pwd
/home/username/dir
dir:510:10$ cd ..
~:511:11$
```

If you're using Bash 4, you can set the `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` shell variable to a number of trailing directory levels to display. But there was a bug in it which was fixed in a maintenance release (4.1, I think).