# Display only the current directory name (not the full path) in Windows CMD Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, prompt

In Windows CMD.EXE, I have my prompt string set to `$P$G`,
so, if my current working directory is

```
C:\Some\long\folder\inner
```

my prompt is like this:

```
C:\Some\long\folder\inner>
```

I want it to show only the last (lowest level) folder name, like this:

```
inner>
```

where "inner" is just the name of the inner-most folder,
and it should automatically change to the inner-most folder of
whichever directory I'm currently inside –
equivalent to the capability discussed in
[Show only current directory name (not full path) on bash prompt](https://superuser.com/q/60555/150988). 
How can I do this?

Comment: what do you want "inner> PROMPT ??" to print in command instead of c:/>. If you want this then you can easily print it by 
PROMPT=inner$GPROMPT ??

Comment: edited the question, hope it's clearer now. "inner" is not some particular piece of text that I want to display, it's actually the name of the folder.

Comment: If there is a simple way then why do you want to go for a typical way, We can simply write it PROMPT=lastdirectory$G
and both will give you the same result.Here, lastdirectory is inner.

Comment: did you want to make a batch file?? To run this then you can get an idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724278/help-writing-dos-script-to-get-get-name-of-the-most-recent-directory-time-creat

Comment: I want it to reflect the current directory *automatically*. I don't see much point of setting it manually.

Comment: I guess [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterPROMPTForCMDEXEOrCoolPromptEnvironmentVariablesAndANiceTransparentMultiprompt.aspx) should set you on the right track. If you want, I’ll provide an in-depth answer later.

Comment: I want the batch equivalent of this: http://superuser.com/questions/60555/show-only-current-directory-name-not-full-path-on-bash-prompt. Sorry for all the confusion with the "inner" stuff.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no possibility I know about to accomplish that unless you hack into `cmd.exe`; you can display the current drive by `prompt $N$G` but not the pure name of the current working directory; you could however append a line-break to the standard prompt like `prompt $P$G$_` if that helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround, if you're willing to change your habits a little.

First of all, pick a directory in your PATH that you can write to. 
Assuming that you're on your own machine, and you have admin rights,
you could use `\Windows` or `\Program Files\something`. 
But it's probably better
to use something like`\Users\username\bin`. 
(Add it to your PATH if you don't already have it there.)

Then create a file there called `CH.BAT`, or something like that,
with the following contents:

```
@echo off
REM Pass the argument(s) to the real "cd".  If it fails, don't do anything else.
cd %*  ||  exit /b
REM Get our current directory name.
set "dirname=%CD%"
:loop
REM Strip off one directory level -- remove everything through the first \.
set "remove_one=%dirname:*\=%"
REM If there's nothing left, that means dirname ENDS with a \.
REM The only (?) way this can happen is if it is the root directory
REM of a filesystem (partition), e.g., C:\.
REM In this case, set the prompt to the normal thing, C:\>.
if "%remove_one%" == ""          goto exit_loop
REM If "%remove_one%" == "%dirname%", that means we are down to
REM the last directory name (i.e., there are no backslashes left).
if "%remove_one%" == "%dirname%" goto exit_loop
set "dirname=%remove_one%"
REM Keep on removing levels until we get to the bottom.
goto loop

:exit_loop
REM To handle the case where a directory name contains dollar sign(s)
REM (e.g., $P$G), replace each $ with $$ to remove its special meaning
REM in the prompt, and just display a $.
set "dirname=%dirname:$=$$%"
prompt %dirname%$G
```

And then get into the habit of typing `ch` instead of `cd`
(or `chdir`, if you're old enough to remember its original name
(which is still supported)). 
I believe that the comments explain it fairly well, but, to recapitulate:

- Invoke `cd` on the command-line argument(s). 
  If it fails, exit the script.
- Use variable substitution
  (`%varname:old=new%`)
  to strip off directory levels. 
  Loop until there's nothing left to do. 
  If the current directory is the root (e.g., `C:\`),
  then the prompt will be `C:\>`
  (since you didn't specify how to handle  that case). 
  If it is something like `C:\top\outer\middle\inner`,
  you will get `inner>`, as requested.
- As we know, dollar signs are special in the prompt. 
  But they are legal in directory names. 
  You can escape dollar signs in the prompt by doubling them;
  i.e., if you put `$$` in the prompt, it will display as `$`. 
  So we replace all dollar sign(s) in the directory name
  with `$$` to get them to display correctly.
- The script hard-codes the current directory name into the prompt string,
  so, if you subsequently accidentally type `cd` instead of `ch`,
  your prompt will not change. 
  If this happens, just type `ch` (or `ch .`)
  to set the prompt based on the new current directory.
- If you ever want to see the full pathname of your current directory,
  type `cd` (or `echo %CD%`).
- I have tested this with directory names that contain spaces
  (and dollar signs), but I haven't tested every legal character. 
  Please let me know if you find a problem.

Naturally, it does no good to name the script `CD.BAT` or `CHDIR.BAT`,
because CMD.EXE always interprets `cd` and `chdir`
as the “change directory” built-in command. 
You can run such a script by typing its pathname,
but obviously that’s infeasible (from a workflow perspective)
as an override/replacement for `cd`.

Comment: Very clever and useful answer. Lots more fun things to add to that final prompt call [here](https://superuser.com/a/1049058/114388).