# Display only current dir without path in Command Prompt windows 10/11

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

I wanted to change cmd prompt from ,,C:/users/____/foldername>" to ,,foldername $ ".. But windows does not provide an easy way to do it so. Had anyone found any solution? If they did, is there any simple way to apply it?

Comment: Window CMD prompt string has limited choice; see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/a-better-prompt-for-cmdexe-or-cool-prompt-environment-variables-and-a-nice-transparent-multiprompt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display only the current directory name (not the full path) in Windows CMD Prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/861828/display-only-the-current-directory-name-not-the-full-path-in-windows-cmd-promp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's possible to change this behavior of command prompt.

An alternative solution is to use a batch script like that :

```
@echo off
:loop
for %%I in (.) do set currentFolder=%%~nxI
set /P commandLine=%currentFolder%$
%commandLine%
goto loop
```

Save this code in a .bat file to have your custom cmd.

Warning : the behavior could be sometime different compare to the true CMD.

Comment: It works as I exptected. Thanks a lot!!