# In Visual Studio Code how can I modify the Terminal prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm familiar with modifying a Terminal prompt similar to this question: "[Show only current directory name (not full path) on bash prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/60555/show-only-current-directory-name-not-full-path-on-bash-prompt)" but I'm looking to **only modify** the Terminal prompt in Visual Studio code.

I'd like to be able to run:

```
export PS1='~/${PWD/*\//} '
```

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code I can modify specify a custom `.bash_profile`? I'm not finding anything from searching the site or

Comment: Try using the [PROMPT command](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html). If it works, then it can be made permanent using the environment variable `PROMPT`.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code offers multiple ways to pass custom information to the shell ([detailed here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration)):

- Pass custom environment variables
- Pass custom arguments on the command line

Using custom environment variables, you could set options that you check for in your custom `.bashrc`. You could then set appropriate options for running inside VS Code.

With custom arguments, you can indeed specify a different `.bashrc`-equivalent, like this:

```
bash --init-file /path/to/file
```

For example, your `settings.json` on Linux could look like this:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["--init-file", "~/.bashrc-vscode"]
}
```

Keep in mind that “Windows” or “Linux” does not refer to the shell type but the OS. So if you’re using Git Bash on Windows, it’s still `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows`.